# Is $\mbox{tr}(A^2)$ always nonnegative?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Does $\mbox{tr}(A^2) \geq 0$ hold for any real matrix $A$?

I think this is true but I am unable to prove this. Any further help is appreciated.

Comment: A useful characterization for the trace of a matrix, is  that equals the sum of eigenvalues. You can use that to get your answer.

Comment: If the matrix takes values in complex numbers then it is true for sure. For real numbers I don't believe it holds.

Comment: Consider the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Is the above matrix a square of some matrix with real entries, then I get the answer?

Comment: TRUSKI, Rahul's matrix is a 90 degree rotation of the real plane, so its square is the 180 degree rotation, i.e. $-I_2$. To answer the question in your comment, it is also the square of a 45 degree rotation, but we don't really need that bit to answer the question, do we :-)

Comment: I understand now. Thanks @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Add a condition that the eigenvalues of $A$ are all real, then it's true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A=\left[\begin{matrix}0 & -1\\2 & 0\end{matrix}\right]$. Square it and see what happens...

Comment: Thanks. This is very nice.